# Why receiver DB is asking for archived WAL files from source DB? (WAL segment already removed)

Tags: postgresql, database-replication, postgresql-11, wal

I have 3 postgres-11 DB servers running with one of them being the source and 2 of them copying data from the source via subscription. 1 of the target DBs is on the same network, whereas the other one is on a different network and separated via firewall. The setup is like this:

```
A (source DB- publication)  ----------(same network)-------> B (target DB - subscription)
                               |
                               |------(firewall)-----------> C (target DB - subscription)
```

Recently I got an error on the source DB that the requested WAL files have been already removed.

```
2021-06-23 10:10:14.937 JST,"user","sourcedb",2xxxx9,"1x.xx.xxx.xxx:2xxxx",xxxxxx.xxx,4,"idle",2021-06-23 10:10:14 JST,15/0,0,ERROR,58P01,"requested WAL segment 0000000100010E0600000030 has already been removed",,,,,,,,,"sub_xxx_xxx_xxx"
```

On checking I saw that subscription on the `target DB C` had failed and stopped. The subscription on `target DB B` had no problem at all (probably because it is on the same network).

The setup on all 3 DBs is same. On `source DB A` and other  2 as well, the files get archived from `pg_wal` to another directory on the disk named `/opt/postgresql/archivewal`.

However, from this `/opt/postgresql/archivewal` folder, **a cron job removes these files every 2 mins** and stores them on another backup server.

Here is the `postgresql.conf` file. It is mostly same for all servers

```
# Connection settings
# -------------------
listen_addresses = '*'
port = 5532
max_connections = 400

tcp_keepalives_idle = 0
tcp_keepalives_interval = 0
tcp_keepalives_count = 0

# Memory-related settings
# -----------------------
shared_buffers = 32GB           # Physical memory 1/4
##DEBUG:  mmap(1652555776) with MAP_HUGETLB failed, huge pages disabled: Cannot allocate memory
#huge_pages = try              # on, off, or try
#temp_buffers = 16MB            # depends on DB checklist
work_mem = 8MB                 # Need tuning
effective_cache_size = 64GB      # Physical memory 1/2
maintenance_work_mem = 512MB
wal_buffers = 64MB

# WAL/Replication/HA   settings
# --------------------
wal_level = logical
synchronous_commit = remote_write
archive_mode = on
archive_command = 'rsync -a %p /opt/postgresql/archivewal/%f'
#archive_command = ':'
max_wal_senders=5
hot_standby = on
restart_after_crash = off
wal_sender_timeout = 5000
wal_receiver_status_interval = 2
max_standby_streaming_delay = -1
max_standby_archive_delay = -1
hot_standby_feedback = on
random_page_cost = 1.5

max_wal_size = 5GB
checkpoint_completion_target = 0.9
checkpoint_timeout = 30min

# Logging settings
# ----------------
log_destination = 'csvlog,syslog'
logging_collector = on
log_directory = 'pg_log'
log_filename = 'postgresql_%Y%m%d.log'
log_truncate_on_rotation = off
log_rotation_age = 1h
log_rotation_size = 0

log_timezone = 'Japan'
log_line_prefix = '%t [%p]: [%l-1] %h:%u@%d:[XXXX]:CODE:%e '

log_statement = 'all'
log_min_messages = info         # DEBUG5
log_min_error_statement = info  # DEBUG5
log_error_verbosity = default
log_checkpoints = on
log_lock_waits = on
log_temp_files = 0
log_connections = on
log_disconnections = on
log_duration = off
log_min_duration_statement = 1000
log_autovacuum_min_duration = 3000ms

track_functions = pl
track_activity_query_size = 8192

# Locale/display settings
# -----------------------
lc_messages = 'C'
lc_monetary = 'en_US.UTF-8'  # ja_JP.eucJP
lc_numeric  = 'en_US.UTF-8'  # ja_JP.eucJP
lc_time     = 'en_US.UTF-8'  # ja_JP.eucJP
timezone = 'Asia/Tokyo'
bytea_output = 'escape'


# Auto vacuum settings
# -----------------------
autovacuum = on
autovacuum_max_workers = 3
autovacuum_vacuum_cost_limit = 200
shared_preload_libraries  = 'pg_stat_statements,auto_explain'

auto_explain.log_min_duration = 10000
auto_explain.log_analyze = on
```

**My question is**: Why did  the `target DB C` ask the `source DB A` for those files, which when I checked in the backup server were removed 10 mins before the error occurred? As per what I read, the source DB will not recycle or archive the files needed by any of the replication slots. It was also proved when I restarted the subscription on `target DB C`, the `pg_wal` size grew to quite an extent and it was copied successfully.

Will extending the interval of removing the files from the archive folder from 2 mins to 10 mins solve it really? I don't wanna hit and try and rather know the exact logic.

This publication-subscription arrangement has been going on for over a year and I have had this problem only twice. Could this be related to a large data volume?

**Edit 1:**
Adding information about the status of current replication

**Source DB**

```
sourcedb=# select * from pg_replication_slots ;
        slot_name        |  plugin  | slot_type | datoid | database | temporary | active | active_pid | xmin | catalog_xmin |  restart_lsn   | confirmed_flush_lsn
-------------------------+----------+-----------+--------+----------+-----------+--------+------------+------+--------------+----------------+---------------------
 sub_xxxx_xxxx_targetdbA | pgoutput | logical   |  16501 | sourcedb  | f         | t      |     208603 |      |     96140914 | 10E82/9404CA50 | 10E82/9E3AFE18
 sub_xxxx_xxxx_targetdbB | pgoutput | logical   |  16501 | sourcedb  | f         | t      |     208175 |      |     96140914 | 10E82/9404CA50 | 10E82/9E3AFDE8
(2 rows)
```

**Target DB A**

```
targetdbA=#select * from pg_stat_subscription;
   subid    |         subname         |  pid   | relid |  received_lsn  |      last_msg_send_time       |    last_msg_receipt_time     | latest_end_lsn |        latest_end_t
ime
------------+-------------------------+--------+-------+----------------+-------------------------------+------------------------------+----------------+--------------------
-----------
 2378695757 | sub_xxxx_xxx_targetdbA | 231891 |       | 10E82/ACE84D98 | 2021-06-25 13:15:51.866896+09 | 2021-06-25 13:15:52.39434+09 | 10E82/AB6BA340 | 2021-06-25 13:15:48
.857865+09
(1 row)
```

**Target DB B**

```
targetdbB=# select * from pg_stat_subscription;
   subid    |       subname       |  pid  | relid |  received_lsn  |      last_msg_send_time       |     last_msg_receipt_time     | latest_end_lsn |        latest_end_time

------------+---------------------+-------+-------+----------------+-------------------------------+-------------------------------+----------------+------------------------
-------
 3479436453 | sub_xxxx_xxx_targetdbB | 99318 |       | 10E83/1D9A8F88 | 2021-06-25 13:20:15.130238+09 | 2021-06-25 13:20:17.868138+09 | 10E83/1D0F2D10 | 2021-06-25 13:20:13.305
298+09
(1 row)
```

**Edit 2:**
This is only my guess, but not sure if it is the real reason. I noticed that the walsender on node A (the source DB) keeps getting killed with the following error.

```
terminating walsender process due to replication timeout
```

And this happens multiple times throughout the day, especially when the data volume on the source node is high.

Most of the times it restarts automatically very quickly. And the receiver node(s) get the missing files from the `pg_wal` or archived WAL folder. But on this particular day (mentioned in the logs above), the process took longer to restart and thus probably missed getting those files.
My `wal_sender_timeout` has been set to 1 min (the conf file shows 5 sec but it was updated later). And the following setting on target nodes:

```
postgres=# show wal_receiver_status_interval ;
 wal_receiver_status_interval
------------------------------
 2s
(1 row)

postgres=# show wal_retrieve_retry_interval ;
 wal_retrieve_retry_interval
-----------------------------
 5s
(1 row)
```

Why the `walsender` is getting dropped repeatedly? Is it because when there is high data volume, the response/acknowledgement from the receiving/target nodes gets lost?

Comment: 'source DB will not recycle or archive the files needed by any of the replication slots'. Are you using slots?  You don't describe setting them up or using them, and the config you show doesn't suggest them, either.

Comment: @jjanes- Added more information. Should I mentioning the process of setting this publication and subscription too?

Comment: That should not have happened, the slot should have prevented it.  Are you using the latest bug fix release of v11?

Comment: I am using version 11.6. Would that include the bug fixes you are referring to? Also was there a specific bug related to slots not being able to prevent such an incident?

Comment: Are you the sole administrator of this machine?  Maybe someone was worried that space was filling up, and so manually removed some files from pg_wal.

Comment: Yes, no one else has the access to these machines. I checked with the network team and they say the traffic during that time through the firewall looks heavy. So my doubts are mostly about that. 
Also, we have another icinga monitoring that keeps checking the time diff between the `last_msg_receipt_time` - `last_msg_send_time` every 5 mins. That didn't raise any alerts either.

Comment: I'm not aware of a specific bug like this fixed since 11.6.  I'm just suspicious of bug-like behavior seen when running older releases.  It could be that a fixed bug could present in multiple ways, not all of which were included in the release notes.

Comment: @jjanes In relation to edit 2 on the question, do you have any idea why wal_sender might be assuming the receiving nodes connection to be inactive?